# Displaying metrics for a list of specific pages from a website

Tags: google-analytics

Can I get a table for a metric (ex: visitors, pageviews) for a specific list (imported as .xls, .csv or .xml) of pages from a Google Analytics tracked website?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this. The quick way is to export the data from Analytics, but that only lets you do 500 pages at a time so if you have hundreds of pages then it's going to take a while. Once you've exported you can then cross reference against your list using the VLOOKUP function.

Alternatively you could write something using the [data API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html).